# How to factorise $6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring

> How to factorise $6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15$?

I've figured out that $$6x^2+5xy+y^2 = (2x+y)(3x+y).$$

But I do not know how I would include $x+2y-15$

$6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15$.

Comment: What do you know about factorization of such polynomials, which tools do you have? Or are you only trying to guess until you happen to find a factorization?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+6x%5E2%2B5xy%2By%5E2%2Bx%2B2y-15

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.Good try thus far. You got the factorization wrong, but it is $2x+y$ times $3x+y$, so  the idea to factorize the first three terms was correct.

Write :
$$
6x^2 + 5xy + y^2 + x + 2y - 15 = (2x+y + a)(3x +y + b)
$$

and now expand and compare coefficients:
$$
6x^2 + 5xy + y^2 + x + 2y - 15 = 6x^2 + 5xy+ y^2 + by + 2bx + 3ax + ay + ab
$$

So what we know by comparing coefficients, is that $2b + 3a = 1$ and $b + a = 2$. This gives after solving that $a = -3$ and $b = 5$, also confirming the fact that $ab =-15$

Hence, the completed factorization is:
$$
6x^2 + 5xy + y^2 + x + 2y - 15 = (2x+y -3)(3x +y + 5)
$$

Comment: I see. Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Thou art welcome.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг But the factorization mentioned in the question was incorrect. I fixed it however,

Comment: @Peter Yes, I saw the earlier incorrect factorization as well. I always say 
"Good try" as if to provide cheer.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Next time you see an error in a question please fix it before answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the quadratic formula on
$$
6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15=6x^2+(5y+1)x+(y^2+2y-15)
$$
The discriminant is $((5y+1)^2-6\cdot4\cdot(y^2+2y-15))$, which turns out to be $(y-19)^2$. Therefore, the roots are
$$
x=\frac{-(5y+1)\pm(y-19)}{12}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Also we can use the following.

$$6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15$$ is a quadratic expression of $y$ and we can calculate the $\Delta$,

which must be $(ax+b)^2$ for some reals $a$ and $b$ because  otherwise, we have an irreducible polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is searched in the form:
$$6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15=(ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f).$$
Plugging $x=0$, it results in:
$$y^2+2y-15=(by+c)(ey+f) \Rightarrow$$
$$(y-3)(y+5)=(by+c)(ey+f) \Rightarrow b=e=1,c=-3,f=5.$$
Plugging $y=0$, it results in:
$$6x^2+x-15=(ax+c)(dx+f)\Rightarrow$$
$$(2x-3)(3x+5)=(ax+c)(dx+f) \Rightarrow a=2,d=3,c=-3,f=5.$$
The parameters correspond, thus:
$$6x^2+5xy+y^2+x+2y-15=(2x+y-3)(3x+y+5).$$